# FindContours function works in main(), but not in a function call

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, vector

I get a run time error while using FindContours function in a function call in OpenCV. I get a run time error stated as follows:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occured in Project.exe.

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

and then the cursor points to a line in the **vector.h** file as follows.

```
void _Assign_rv(_Myt&& _Right)
    {   // assign by moving _Right
    this->_Swap_all((_Myt&)_Right);
    this->_Myfirst = _Right._Myfirst;           // The cursor points here
    this->_Mylast = _Right._Mylast;     
    this->_Myend = _Right._Myend;

    _Right._Myfirst = pointer();
    _Right._Mylast = pointer();
    _Right._Myend = pointer();
    }
```

But findContours function works in the main() function. I could not quite understand it.

The code runs fine without using FindContours function. **I have passed the right images to the function.**

I explored a lot about this problem. I found there are many questions with findContours function, which are not rightly answered or have answers which are not enough to solve this problem.
    I thought the problem might be with CLI. But, the problem persisted with the console application too.

For your information, I use openCV248 in visual studio 2012. My code snippet in the Windows form file "MyForm.h"

```
vector<vector<cv::Point>> Image_Contours;
vector<Vec4i> Image_Hierarchy;

FillContours(ColorImage,Image_Contours,Image_Hierarchy); // Function Call to do basic image filtering and find the contours

FillContours(&ColorImage, & vector<vector<cv::Point>>& ContoursP, vector<cv::Vec4i> &HierarchyP)
{
     .......... // Filtering operations of ColorImage
     cvtColor(ImageFiltered, GrayConverted, CV_BGR2GRAY);
     findContours(GrayConverted, ContoursP, HierarchyP, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
}
```

I also used a simple existing GRAY image in the findContours function instead of such a function call and still I got a run time error.

Comment: can you post your `findContours` call code snippet and how you try to access the contour data afterwards?

Comment: The message is probably correct: your vector is corrupt. Where that happens is impossible to guess.

Comment: @Micka : Please see the edited version

Comment: @molbdnilo: So, is there a conflict between findContours and vectors ? This version of findContours produces this error ?. I tried to see the definition of this function. But it is hidden in some way or maybe dynamic. So could not zero in into the cause.

Comment: can you add what you do after `findContours` (e.g. how you try to access the contours) or are you 100% sure that the error occurs within the `findContours` function?

Comment: @Micka: I didn't do anything more. I just tried to run after using that function.

Comment: @Micka: Yes, I am pretty sure. I could do all other image manipulations before this function. To say the least, I used an existing gray image and passed into this function to get the same error. For more information: I got a different run-time error with the same FindContours function before some trials: It was "This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in MyProject.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded." and then the cursor points to a different function called **void _Tidy()** in the **line this->_myFirst = pointer();** in the **vector.h** file.

Comment: can you try to create a temporary parameters? e.g. `vector<vector<cv::Point>> ContoursX; vector<cv::Vec4i> HierarchyX; findContours(GrayConverted, ContoursX, HierarchyX, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` within `FillContours` instead of using the input parameter?

Comment: @Micka: I tried also that way. I just used a gray image which is an existing one into this function instead of using this FillContours function call

Comment: but did you use an "old" vector for contour output, or did you use a new/clean/uncorrupted/whatever one?

Comment: @Micka: I don't have any old vectors. I used the one as an output, which is declared in the code snippet.

Comment: did you `.clear()` it before each findContours call? In your situation I would try to use a completely new, temporary vector for contours and hierarchy just to test whether the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Micka: Now I found out that findContours works in the main(), but it does not work in a separate function call. Strange for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68599/discussion-between-karthik-elan-and-micka).